# How to catch Term action signal in parent process?

Tags: c++, c, linux, process, signals

I'm new in LINUX C programming, my task is to write a program about process.

I need to handle two process, parent one and child one.

My goal is to let parent fork a process(child process),and then child process to execute a program which may terminate fail. Parent process wait child process to terminate, and get the signal which is launched from child signal, such as abort or segmentation fault.

However, I encounter some problems.

I found that "Core Action" signal can be detected easily, but "Term action" cannot be detected!!

"Term action" signal, such as SIGALRM(14) or SIGINT(2), cannot be detected.
It seems to be categorized as terminated success.

Here is my code :

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <errno.h>
using namespace std;


bool check = true; 

void mySignal( int sig ){
    int status; 
    pid_t childPid = wait( &status ) ; 


    if( WIFEXITED( status ) ){
        printf("The child is terminated success!!\n"); 
    }
    else{
        if( WIFSIGNALED( status ) ){
            int termsig = WTERMSIG( status ) ;
            printf("termsig = %d %d\n",status, termsig ) ;  
        }
    }
    check = false ; 
}


int main( int argc , char *argv[] ){

    signal( SIGCHLD, mySignal ) ; 
    pid_t pid = fork() ; 


    if( pid < 0 ){
        printf("fork error\n");
        exit( -1 ) ;
    }
    else if( pid == 0 ){
        execl( argv[1], NULL );
        exit( 0 ) ;
    }

    while( check ) ; 
    return 0 ; 
}
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem ??

Answer (score 0):

```
void mySignal( int sig ){
  int status; 
  pid_t childPid = wait( &status ) ; 


  if( WIFEXITED( status ) ){
     printf("The child is terminated success!!\n"); 
  }

  if( WIFSIGNALED( status ) ){
     int termsig = WTERMSIG( status ) ;
     printf("termsig = %d %d\n",status, termsig ) ;  
  }
  check = false ; 
}
```

A signal does not always end a program, making your conditional pointless.

Comment: Oh!! Thanks for your reminding!! I will consider this issue :)

Comment: @ChihMin don't forget to validate an answer if someone fixed your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
if(WEXITED(status)){
  printf("Child %d exited with exit code %d.\n", (int)pid, WEXITSTATUS(status));
  // Note that a non-zero exit status normally indicates some kind of error.
}
else if(WIFSIGNALED(status)){
  printf(
    "Child %d terminated with signal %d, with%s a core dump.\n",
    (int)pid, WTERMSIG(status), WCOREDUMP(status)? "": "out"
  );
}
else if(WSTOPPED(status)){
  printf("Child %d was stopped by signal %d.\n", (int)pid, WSTOPSIG(status));
}
else{
  fprintf(stderr, "Unexpected signal condition.\n");
}
```

As noted above, a non-zero exit status normally indicates error.  So should you do in your code: the `exit(0)` just after `execl()` will only be executed if the call to `execl()` fails, thus you'd rather say something like `exit(1)` or `exit(EX_UNAVAILABLE)` (from `<sysexits.h>`).

Comment: But finally, I found out my alarm test program has something wrong so that my parent process can't receive SIGALRM signal XD